# Not able to access individual element from sublist

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

I am a beginner in `java`. I want to read elements one by one in `sublist`.

```
public class ListFirst {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Integer>list1= Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40);
        List<Integer>list2=Arrays.asList(100,200,300,400);
        List<List<Integer>>bigList= new ArrayList<>();
       
         // I want to access an element of bigList one by one. how to do that?
        
    }

}
```

If there is no `sublist` I can print using `for loop` upto `list.size()` and `list.get()` to print but here element is list itself..so I dont know how to read. could you please help me with that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do. You defined a List of Lists. But what do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: I want to extract element one by one from bigList. means printing 10,20,30,40,100,200,300,400.  .

Comment: Use two nested for loops, the external loop iterates overs bigList, extracting sublists, the internal read elements from the current sublist

Answer (score 3):

I modified your code to achieve what you wanted to do:

```java
public class ListFirst {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Integer>list1= Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40);
        List<Integer>list2=Arrays.asList(100,200,300,400);

        List<List<Integer>>bigList= new ArrayList<>();

        bigList.add(list1);
        bigList.add(list2);
       
        for (List<Integer> list : bigList) {
            for (Integer i : list) {
                System.out.print(i.intValue() + " ");
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

An alternative would be to not use nested `List` for storing your `Integer`s:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<Integer>list1= Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40);
    List<Integer>list2=Arrays.asList(100,200,300,400);

    // bigList is a list of Integers not list of lists
    List<Integer>bigList= new ArrayList<>();

    bigList.addAll(list1); // add all elements from list1
    bigList.addAll(list2); // add all elements from list2
    
    for (Integer i : bigList) {
        System.out.print(i.intValue() + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the lists have bee added to `bigList`, you can iterate it using the [for-each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) as shown below:

```
bigList.add(list1);
bigList.add(list2);

for (List<Integer> list : bigList) {
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/jeVkxk)

Using the traditional loop, you can print `bigList` as shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bigList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(bigList.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
bigList.stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Output:

```
10
20
30
40
100
200
300
400
```